# Show that $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2-z}$ converges uniformly by Weierstrass M Test

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, uniform-convergence

> Show that for each $r>0$ the series $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2-z}$$ converges uniformly on the set $E_r=\{z\mid |z|\leq r, z\neq k^2 \,\,\text{for} \,\,k=0,1,2,\cdots\}$

I wish to use the Weierstrass M-Test to show that this series converges uniformly. My intuition is to use $M_k = \frac{1}{k^2-r}$, but this is not necessarily positive, so I'm stuck.

Any hints as to picking an $M_k$ would be most appreciated. Then I will continue to show that all the conditions of the M-Test are satisfied.

UPDATE: The question does not specifically state to use the Weierstrass M-Test, but it was how the preceding few questions were solved. Any other methods of showing uniform convergence are welcome.

Comment: You can skip any finite initial part of the series to test for uniform convergence. So consider only the $k$ with $k^2 > r$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Okay, then I can use the $M_k$ I suggested above and the terms are positive. However, another requirement of the test is that $|f_k(z)| \leq M_k$ for $z\in E_r$. We have $|k^2-z|\leq |k^2|-|z| \leq k^2-r$ by the Triangle Inequality and definition of $E_r$. But that would mean $\left|\frac{1}{k^2-z}\right| \geq \frac{1}{k^2-r} = M_k$, which doesn't help for the test.

Comment: You have your inequalities the wrong way, $\lvert k^2-z\rvert \geqslant \lvert k^2\rvert - \lvert z\rvert \geqslant k^2-r$, so it works fine.

Comment: @DanielFischer Wow! Can't believe I didn't see that. This makes sense now. Thanks for your help. I will post a solution shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of Daniel Fischer identifying my mistake, I use the Weierstrass M-Test with $M_k = \frac{1}{k^2-r}$.

First, we assume $k^2>r$, as this doesn't change the test for uniform convergence, so that $M_k$ are positive terms.

Then, we need to ensure that $|f_k(z)|\leq M_k$ for $z\in E_r$. We have $|k^2-z|\geq |k^2|-|z| \geq k^2-r$ by the Triangle Inequality and definition of $E_r$. Thus, $$\frac{1}{k^2-z}\leq \frac{1}{k^2-r} = M_k$$ so the condition is satisfied.

Lastly, we need $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty M_k = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2-r}$$ to converge for all $r>0$. To show this, we use the limit comparison test with $b_k = \sum_{k=1}^\infty M_k$ and $a_k = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2}$. Then,

$$c=\lim_{k \to \infty} \left(\frac{1}{k^2}\right)\left(\frac{k^2-r}{1}\right) = 1.$$ Since $0<c<\infty$, both series either converge or diverge. We know $\sum a_k$ converges since it is a $p$-series with $p=2$. Thus, $\sum M_k$ converges.

We can therefore apply the Weierstrass M-Test to conclude that $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{k^2-z}$ converges uniformly on $E_r$.