# Convergence of $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{z-n^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

I try to show that the following series converges for all $z \in \mathbb C$ (except the obvious poles). 
$$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{z-n^2}$$
Since we have $n^2$ in the denominator I tried to use comparision test, but I couldn't achieve a suitable inequality (even tried to transform the fraction in a geometric series, but it didn't help). I would appreciate some help :)

Comment: Show that the series converges uniformly on all compact sets. Pick $R \in (0,+\infty)$, show that the series converges uniformly on $\{ z : \lvert z\rvert \leqslant R\}$.

Comment: Similar question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/992705/show-that-sum-k-0-infty-frac1k2-z-converges-uniformly-by-weierstrass?rq=1) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1794713/uniform-convergence-of-sum-n-infty-infty-frac1n2-z2-on-any-dis?rq=1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an example, if $|z|<N$, then $|z-n^2|>n^2-n=n(n-1)$ for $n\ge N$.

Similarly, you could find $|z-n^2|>\frac12 n^2$ if $n$ is large enough.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Try showing that $|\frac{1}{z-n^2}|\le \frac{1}{n^2}$ . (Edited)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/714325)

Comment: Sorry i am new to this ! Don't be harsh :)

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Although not a full answer, this answer provides a hint for the OP. Such hints are completely appropriate in here, though maybe explicitly pointing out this is a hint is desirable.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I don't want to give full answers if a solution is short enough.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen: At 3532 reputation points, you should already know that such hints are perfectly acceptable on MSE.

Comment: I edited my comment. Bash on me ! My first answer was not good

Answer (score 0):

We assume that $z \notin E=\left\{1,4,9,16,\cdots \right\}$, then one may write, as $n \to \infty$,
$$
\left|\frac{1}{z-n^2}\right|=\frac{1}{n^2}\cdot \frac{1}{\left|1-\frac{z}{n^2}\right|} \sim \frac{1}{n^2}
$$ giving the *absolute convergence* thus the *pointwise convergence* of the given series over the above set $E$.